# Making a div full width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://preview.derekthiele.com/p01

Basically, I created this div to act as the site background, but I can't seem to make the whitespaces on the sides and the bottom of site go away. I've tried using background-size and changing the margins and such. Doesn't seem to be changing anything. Anyone have any solutions as to how to make the background cover the entire site (top to bottom, left to right).

Answer (score 4):

You need to zero out the body, which by default has a margin:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

This is a good reason to use a reset sheet. A popular one is [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```